# Inserting Data into the MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have html form like below. I want to add data to the database table **itemspoinfo**. I want to done that functionality as follows;

- If first drug name and quantity given add those  to the database.
- If first 2 drug names and quantities given add those to the database.
  (as 2 separate records along with POno,and Date)
- As this up to 5 records have to be able to record in to the database

I can't find a solution for this Please Help me.

What I have done so far;

```
   <%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    if(request.getParameter("send")!=null){
        String scom=request.getParameter("scompany");
        String porderno=request.getParameter("pono");
        String bdate=request.getParameter("date");

        String drug1=request.getParameter("d1");
        String qty1=request.getParameter("q1");
        String drug2=request.getParameter("d2");
        String qty2=request.getParameter("q2");
        String drug3=request.getParameter("d3");
        String qty3=request.getParameter("q3");
        String drug4=request.getParameter("d4");
        String qty4=request.getParameter("q4");
        String drug5=request.getParameter("d5");
        String qty5=request.getParameter("q5");


        //getting todaydate
        Date date = new Date();
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

        String sql = "INSERT INTO purchaseorderinfo SET Supplier ='"+scom+"', PONo='"+porderno+"', ExpectedDate='"+bdate+"', PODate='"+timestamp+"' ";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);



        if((scom!=null && scom.length()>0)
            && (porderno!=null && porderno.length()>0)
            && (bdate!=null && bdate.length()>0)
            && (drug1!=null && drug1.length()>0)
            && (qty1!=null && qty1.length()>0)){


            pst.execute();

            String sql2="INSERT INTO itemspoinfo SET PODate=?, PONo=?, ItemName=?, Qty=?,";
            pst2=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
            pst2.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
            pst2.setString(2, porderno);



          %>
          <script language="javascript">
                alert("Sucessfuly Sent to "+scom);
          </script>
          <%    
        }
    }
%>
```

[image]

Comment: dont use java codes in jsp page

Comment: You are using `update` statement or `insert` statement?

Comment: You might want to read about [Hibernate(ORM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(Java))

Comment: I agree with @SuhailGupta . Please use some ORM (probably Hibernate) for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()`.

Try the following code:

```
String sql2="INSERT INTO itemspoinfo (PODate, PONo, ItemName,Qty) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        pst2=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
        // to check drugs details are added or not.
        int noofdrugs = 0;
        if (drug1!=null && drug1.length()>0)
            && (qty1!=null && qty1.length()>0)) {
            pst2.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
            pst2.setString(2, porderno);
            pst2.setString(3, drug1);
            pst2.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(qty1));
            pst2.addBatch();

            noofdrugs++;
        }

        if (drug2!=null && drug2.length()>0)
            && (qty2!=null && qty2.length()>0))
        {
            pst2.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
            pst2.setString(2, porderno);
            pst2.setString(3, drug2);
            pst2.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(qty2));
            pst2.addBatch();

            noofdrugs++;
        }

        if (drug3!=null && drug3.length()>0)
            && (qty3!=null && qty3.length()>0))
        {
            pst2.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
            pst2.setString(2, porderno);
            pst2.setString(3, drug3);
            pst2.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(qty3));
            pst2.addBatch();

            noofdrugs++;
        }

        if (drug4!=null && drug4.length()>0)
            && (qty4!=null && qty4.length()>0))
        {
            pst2.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
            pst2.setString(2, porderno);
            pst2.setString(3, drug4);
            pst2.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(qty4));
            pst2.addBatch();

            noofdrugs++;
        }

        if (drug5!=null && drug5.length()>0)
            && (qty5!=null && qty5.length()>0))
        {
            pst2.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
            pst2.setString(2, porderno);
            pst2.setString(3, drug5);
            pst2.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(qty5));
            pst2.addBatch();

            noofdrugs++;
        }

        if (noofdrugs>0) {
            pstmt.executeBatch();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First write a separate fuction to insert Items into the database.

```
    void insertItemReord(timestamp, porderno, drug, qty)
    {
        // SQL STUFF
    }
```

Then call it appropriately.

```
       if((scom!=null && scom.length()>0)
            && (porderno!=null && porderno.length()>0)
            && (bdate!=null && bdate.length()>0)
        {
            pst.execute();

            if (drug1!=null && drug1.length()>0)
                && (qty1!=null && qty1.length()>0))
            {
                insertItemReord(timestamp, porderno, drug1, qty1);
            }

            if (drug2!=null && drug2.length()>0)
                && (qty2!=null && qty2.length()>0))
            {
                insertItemReord(timestamp, porderno, drug2, qty2);
            }

            if (drug3!=null && drug3.length()>0)
                && (qty3!=null && qty3.length()>0))
            {
                insertItemReord(timestamp, porderno, drug3, qty3);
            }

            if (drug4!=null && drug4.length()>0)
                && (qty4!=null && qty4.length()>0))
            {
                insertItemReord(timestamp, porderno, drug4, qty4);
            }

            if (drug5!=null && drug5.length()>0)
                && (qty5!=null && qty5.length()>0))
            {
                insertItemReord(timestamp, porderno, drug5, qty5);
            }

              %>
              <script language="javascript">
                    alert("Sucessfuly Sent to "+scom);
              </script>
              <%    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

create a package called utility and then write the DBconnection code in the utility package.

```
public class DBconnection {

public static Connection getConnection() {// set the db connection
    boolean status = false;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "login";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "";

    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);           

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
      if (conn != null) {
           try {

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (pst != null) {
            try {

            } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
        if (rs != null) {
            try {

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return conn;
}
```

}

then create a new java file write the query in a another package.

```
public class Registration {
// new user registration method

public static boolean register(String firstname,String lastname,String email,String username,String password) {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst1, pst2;
    int rs1, rs2;

    boolean status = false;
    try {
        DBconnection dbops = new DBconnection();
        conn = dbops.getConnection();//create connection
        System.out.println("--getconnection-->new user");
        //inert values to the register table
        pst1 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO register(firstname,lastname,email,username,password) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        pst1.setString(1, firstname);
        pst1.setString(2, lastname);
        pst1.setString(3, email);
        pst1.setString(4, username);
        pst1.setString(5, password);
        rs1 = pst1.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("--Execute Query-->new user");
        //System.out.println(rs1);
        if (rs1 == 1) {
            //insert values to users table
            pst2 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users(username,password) values(?,?)");
            pst2.setString(1, username);
            pst2.setString(2, password);

            rs2 = pst2.executeUpdate();
            if (rs2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("inserted succesfully");
                status = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("not insert to users table - something went wrong");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("not insert to register table - username error");
            status = false;
        }

    }catch(SQLException se) {
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

this funtion is called by a servlet and return a boolean value.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if (Registration.register(firstname,lastname,email,username,password)) {
        out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Account Created</p>");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } else {
        out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Error Occured In User Registration</p>");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("newuser.jsp");
        rd.include(request,response);
    }
```

jsp is the view ,servelet is the controller and java file is the model.
I think you get the idea.